# 400 Error for API call Ruby on Rails App using Rest Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest-client

I am attempting to authenticate with a supplier's API, but I keep getting a 400 error. Mind you, it works fine with their "Mock Server"

The code I have is:

```
def perform(*args)
    require 'rest_client'

    values = {"email": "not_telling@hotmail.com",
      "password": ENV['PASSWORD']
    }

    headers = {
      :content_type => 'application/json',
      :accept => 'application/json'
    }

    body = begin
      RestClient.post 'https://beta.b2bapi.trevcoinc.com/api/v1/login', values, headers
      rescue => e
      e.response.body
    end
    fb_response = JSON.parse(body)

  end
```

The response I am getting is

```
{"error"=>"Email is missing!", "status"=>"400"}
```

Is something wrong with my syntax here? I don't know why it is saying the email is missing.

EDIT: API Docs at https://beta.b2bapi.trevcoinc.com/#documentation/

Comment: well, you're passing an `email` param, but beyond that it's hard to say without knowing the API specs. At least your request is going through, so at this point the best thing to do is doublecheck the API documentation

Comment: documentation is at https://beta.b2bapi.trevcoinc.com/#documentation/

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell where the problem lies, perhaps you are not sending the correct payload format/structure (I cannot access the link to the docs, its prompting me for authentication).

When I use RestClient I prefer the verbose format so I can see/control exactly whats happening:

```
headers = {
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
}
url = "https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos"
body = {
  "some" => "content"
}
res = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post, url: url, headers: headers, payload: body.to_json)
```

Try that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not serializing your `values` hash to JSON. Rest Client unfortunately doesn't understand JSON directly, so even if you set a content-type it will encode your payload hash to a string using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding.

Have you tried `values.to_json` instead? (This explicitly encodes to a JSON string.)

Comment: I have tried that also, actually. I tested the endpoint with hurl.it and I am still getting a 500 error. Unless I am putting the wrong thing in the body...

Comment: Hmm. Is it the same error message "Email is missing" as before? Do you really mean 500 error? HTTP status 400 suggests a client error, while 500 is an internal server error.